# Area 51 Share buttons are outdated

Tags: bug, area-51

The share button for Twitter on Area 51 looks dated, and none of the buttons are retina display optimized. An itch to scratch would be to switch the "t" to a bird and/or retinize those images.

[image: A51 Sharing]

Comment: Not really a bug, unless the sharing itself is broken. Since the Area 51 code base is "frozen", I doubt this will be ever done though, as they are only fixing critical bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, Area 51 hasn't have an update for a very long time here.

It would be nice to see an more up-to-date version of the logos for the social communities. Twitter definitely needs to change to its newer logo and probably other sites, like Gmail and other now unrecognizeable sites. Hopefully, a mod comes with a big [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and finishes this before it becomes a 2016 resolution.